# Can I build a cluster with Mac and Linux computers?

Tags: linux, mac, cluster

I do video editing on a Mac and I'd like to setup a cluster for distributed rendering. I don't really have the money to buy several Macs and make a cluster from those (besides, [Xgrid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xgrid) is dead). How can I setup a Linux cluster so it can be used by a Mac?

Comment: What program are you using to do the rendering?

Comment: I'm using Adobe Premiere, but preferable I'd like a whole cluster that is computer-wide accessible. I'm trying to be open, i.e., if I ever switch away from Premiere (I've already switched once)

Comment: So far as I know, there is no standard for rendering clusters that is supported by different rendering programs. Do you know of one?

Comment: No. I did a bit of research and I can't find anything. That's kinda what my question was about.

Comment: In my limited experience with rendering, it didn't really matter what OS was running the rendering application. I had rendered with 3DSMAX on both Mac and Windows machines.

Comment: But what if I wanted to do an Xcode build and wanted to use the cluster? (hypothetically speaking)